# How can I find parameter of the rational map?

Tags: systems-of-equations, rational-functions, numerical-calculus, complex-dynamics, experimental-mathematics

I have a family of rational maps $f$ ( the Blaschke fraction ) with one complex parameter  $\rho$:

$$f(z) = \rho z^2 \frac{z-3}{1-3z}$$

I want to find $\rho$ such that map $f$ has a [parabolic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_points_of_complex_quadratic_mappings#Stability_of_periodic_points_(orbit)_-_multiplier) period 3 cycle on the unit circle.

So $\rho$ should be a solution of system of equations:

$$ \begin{cases}f^3(z_0) = z_0 \\ 
|(f^3)'(z_0)| = 1
\end{cases}$$

where

- $f^3(z) = f(f(f(z)0)))$ is 3-rd [iteration of function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function) f
- $(f^3)'(z_0)$ is the first derivative of $f^3$ with respect to $z$ at $z_0$
- $z_0$ is the point from period 3 parabolic cycle

but [computing derivative of iterated function is hard](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Mathematics/Derivative)

The image of dynamic plane with Julia set:

[image]

It is fig 3 from [paper : Near Parabolic Renormalization for Unicritical Holomorphic Maps by Arnaud Chéritat](http://amj.math.stonybrook.edu/pdf-Springer-final/020-0172.pdf)

I know that $\rho$ has a modulus equal to one (complex number):

$$ |\rho| = 1 $$

My first try was easy solution ( point on the unit circle with angle in turns = 1/3)

$$ \rho =  e^{2 \pi i / 3} =  -0.5 +0.8660254037844386 i$$

Then the period 3 cycle is on the unit cirlce but the cycle is not parabolic and the image is different.

**Q. How can I find such $\rho$ using algebra or numerical root finding ? How can I solve above system of equations ?**

Comment: does "a parabolic 3-cycle on the unit circle" mean $|\rho|=1$ or $|z_0|=1$ (or both?)?

Comment: @Claude Good question. I do not know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is an approximation of the answer using [brute force and visual analysis](https://fractalforums.org/noobs-corner/76/can-you-identify-this-fractal/4776).

First [analyze the map f](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_in_the_complex_plane/analysis)

- find critical points
- compute Mandelbrot set
- find parameter $\rho$ : point on the unit circle which is parabolic point : cusp or a root

So there are 3 critical points :

- 2 finite critical  points : z=1.0 i z= 0.0
- infinity

Here is parameter plane ( rho plane)
[image: full set]

Here zoom around cusp point ( black)  on the unit circle ( white)

[image: zoom]

So $\rho \approx -0.6170144002709304 +0.7869518599370003*I$

Here is [dynamic plane ( z plane ) with Julia and Fatou sets](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Fatou_sets_for_Blaschke_fraction_f(z)_%3D_rho_*_z%5E2_*_(z-3)_over_(1-3z).png)

[image]

There are 3 [Fatou components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_Fatou_components):

- (white = 255) basin of attraction to infinity
- ( light gray = 195) basin of attraction to fixed point z=0 ( superattracting) with critical point z=0
- (dark gray = 135) basin of parabolic period 3 cycle ( critical point z= 1)

Increasing precision of $\rho$ value : there are two 3 point cycle. Choose rho such that 2 cycles join into one cycle.

$$\rho = e^{2 \pi i t}$$

t is changing from 0.3558289901601067 to 0.3558800000000000

Final rho (t)  = e^(2*pi*t*i) is
rho =  -0.6172665900123702 +0.7867540637673888*I  with  turn(rho) =0.3558800000000000  and   radius = 1.0000000000000000

[image: 0.3558289901601067]
[image]
[image]
[image]

On the last image critical orbit goss to limit cycle from both sides . I think that it is numerical error .
Rho value seem to be good